# TRAMP on Windows connects to Linux but not to OSX (macOS)

Tags: osx, microsoft-windows, tramp

Using Emacs-25.2.1 on Windows XP (and on 7, too) I can connect to my Raspberry Pi (Rasppian OS) using TRAMP and the plink method and it works flawlessly. But when I try to connect to my Mac mini (OSX 10.7.4), after I input the password it hangs on with the **"Found remote shell prompt..."** message. The shell on OSX is plain old bash with no fancy configuration in **~/.bash_profile** and the sshd is the default one at **/usr/sbin**

If I try to connect directly from the **CMD** or **MSYS** shell to the OSX e.g.

> $ plink macmini@lionserver.home

It connects flawlessly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Parts of `debug tramp/ssh` related to `locale` from the *Linux* connection:

> 12:40:09.589843 tramp-send-command (6) # locale -a
>
> 12:40:09.655846 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) #
>
> C
>
> C.UTF-8
>
> en_GB.utf8
>
> en_US.utf8
>
> POSIX
>
> tr_TR
>
> tr_TR.iso88599
>
> tr_TR.utf8
>
> turkish
>
> 12:40:09.709849 tramp-open-connection-setup-interactive-shell (5) # Setting coding system to ‘utf-8’ and ‘utf-8-unix’

Parts of `debug tramp/ssh` related to `locale` from the *OSX* connection:

> 12:33:56.549506 tramp-send-command (6) # locale -a
>
> 12:33:56.655512 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) #
>
> af_ZA
>
> af_ZA.ISO8859-1
>
> af_ZA.ISO8859-15
>
> af_ZA.UTF-8
>
> tr_TR
>
> tr_TR.ISO8859-9
>
> tr_TR.UTF-8
>
> ....
>
> C
>
> POSIX
>
> 12:33:56.709515 tramp-open-connection-setup-interactive-shell (5) # Setting coding system to    utf-8-hfs    and    utf-8-hfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this kind of problem is related to your remote shell prompt. Set `tramp-verbose` to 6 (or to 10, if it doesn't help), and rerun your test. If the Tramp traces don't tell you what's up, contact the Tramp tower via email, `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

**Edit:** After investigation on the Tramp ML it has been shown, that this was a bug in Tramp. Will be fixed with the next Tramp 2.3.4 release.

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. I've just added the *trace-output* buffer. Actually I had aleady looked into that but couldn't find any useful info in there, or does it actually contain useful info? So I've added the messages related to Tramp connection, too.

Comment: It's not really the Tramp traces I wanted to see. There must be a buffer `*debug tramp/ssh macmini@g4.ev*` which is relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've copied that buffers output into this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqr75lxf3e9rilf/TRAMP.txt?dl=0

Comment: I still believe we shall trace it on the Tramp mailing list, what we're doing here exceeds the offer of stackeexchange. In short: your remote Mac does not offer a utf8 locale, see the output of `locale -a`. Likely, this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In the attached .txt file, I had removed the lines of locale output because they were too long. Now I edited the original post to include those lines. Btw, both Windows machines are using the turkish language as default. If it cannot be solved after this stage, I might as well post it to the Tramp mailing list.

Comment: Pls write to the Tramp ML. Experience shows, that it doesn't pay to review shortened Tramp traces. It always happens that the problem is found at places we didn't expect. Therefore, I always prefer to see full traces. And promised, you'll find me on the Tramp ML.

Comment: Hello I've just written to the Tramp mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple deprecated bash in favour of zsh, a message appears on login about ‘default interactive shell is now zsh’. This seems to mess with Tramp.

To disable it, add 
`export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1`
to your .bash_profile

Comment: Good comment. However this issue was solved and afterwards never popped up again

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (connecting to Mac OS from Windows using plink hanged on `Found remote shell prompt`). After turning logging verbosity of tramp to 10 I was able to see that tramp was waiting to receive the response of a remote shell command. The response was in the log, but it was terminated by two repetitions of `tramp-end-of-output` variable which contains an MD5 session identifier. The regular expression in `tramp-wait-for-output` function was expecting only one session identifier to indicate the end of response, so it kept waiting.

I fixed it by changing the regexp

```
format "[^#$\n]*%s\r?$" (regexp-quote tramp-end-of-output)
```

in `tramp-sh.el` file to

```
format "[^#$\n]*\\(%s\\)+\r?$" (regexp-quote tramp-end-of-output)
```

to allow for multiple occurrences of `tramp-end-of-output` string.

After making the change, I needed to recompile the file by executing

```
emacs -Q --batch -f batch-byte-compile "<path_to_file>/tramp-sh.el"
```

Afterward, I was able to connect without problems.

Comment: where is this file, i can't find it